# In Netlogo, how do you move a turtle to the other end of its link?

Tags: netlogo

I've created two breeds of turtles in my simulation: one is a regular turtle and the other is a halo that is intended to overlap each turtle. Whenever a turtle is hatched (either created as part of the setup procedure or created with netlogo's hatch function), a halo is also hatched and linked by calling a separate make-halo function.

```
create turtles turtle-initial-number
;;(all the turtle genes are set here)
if halos-enabled [make-halo] 

to make-halo
  hatch-halos 1
  [ set size sight-radius * 2 + 1
    set shape "square"
    set color lput 64 extract-rgb color 
    __set-line-thickness 0.5
    create-link-from myself
    [ tie
      hide-link ] ]
end
```

Due to some interactions I've implemented, sometimes the turtles and the halos become detached from one another, so I'd like to add a step at the end of each tick where all halos snap back to their turtles where they belong. Is there a way to move the halo or set its coordinates to the turtle at the other end of the link?

The other option is to solve whatever is happening when the disconnect occurs. I have another breed of turtle (people) who can "push" others with this push-away function below. Turtles (and their halos) occupying the 9 squares in front of the person are pushed forward along the same direction at the person is facing. When they are pushed, for some reason the turtle isn't at the centre of the halo anymore.

```
to push-away  
  ask people [
    let push-dir heading
    ask patch-ahead 2 
    [ask turtles-here 
      [set heading push-dir
       fd 2]
    ask neighbors
      [ask turtles-here 
        [set heading push-dir
        fd 2]
        ] 
    ] 
  ]
end
```

Comment: this isn't an answer, but i noticed you have constructions like `ask patchset [ask turtles-here [...]]`. These can be replaced with `ask turtles-on patchset []`

Comment: thanks, that will be cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, the `tie` should link the movements. But to snap the halo to its turtle, you can `ask` the halo to `move-to` the turtle. The only trick will be identifying the correct turtle and you haven't shown enough of your code for me to sort out the identification for you.

I suggest you actually add a variable to the halos that records their turtle rather than using a link. If the link has no other purpose, there is no need to create all those extra model entities. You would use it like this:

```
halos-own [my-owner]

to make-halo
  hatch-halos 1
  [ set size sight-radius * 2 + 1
    set shape "square"
    set color lput 64 extract-rgb color 
    __set-line-thickness 0.5
    set my-owner myself      ; this is the new line
 ]
end

to push-away
  <all the code you have already>
  ask halos
  [ move-to my-owner
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think the identification could be pretty complicated because I have multiple breeds who may or may not have halos (toggle switches). My code is fairly complex to post here, there are a lot of things going on and multiple files. Maybe it would help if I posted where exactly the disconnect between the turtle and the halo occurs. I'll add it to my question!

Comment: At some point, you must assign the halo to the turtle, probably around the code you first posted. That's the code I want thanks.

Comment: I added additional code. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: see expanded answer

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I didn't realize you could use an agent's ID as a value, this is so helpful.